# Initializing and accessing component properties directly from a service: Angular2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to persist some data even when the view (via routing) is changed and the component is destroyed from the DOM. The approach I'm taking is storing that data to a singleton service and store that data directly on the service, and when the component is recreated again I can re-assign the component properties from service. This reassigning is not working somehow. So my questions is, can I use those properties directly from the service? So instead of doing something like this when the component is created again:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.var1 = this.someService.var1;
  console.log(this.var1);
}
```

can I do,

```
someFunction {
  console.log(this.someService.var1);
}
```

So here I'm not assigning the values from the service back the values in the component, but using the service values directly for reading and writing, and I'm thinking of accessing them directly in the template also. Is this a good practice?
Also, for persisting the data, is there a reuse component routing strategy?

Comment: why is this `this.var1 = this.someService.var1;` not working?

Comment: Yes you can reuse those properties from the service.  Just create a function in the service to return the values you want and call it when the component is created again.  And create another function in the service to set the values and call it when you want to update them.

Comment: @Maximus, so the var1 is actually working on ngOnInit, but when another value in the component is assigned to var1 it gets updated but the template doesn't render the updated values, and I'm using one way data binding. But if I use the service var directly during the assignment of values and reading them directly in template, then it works fine. Also, the component var1 shows the correct values in console but the template doesnt render it, which is weird

Comment: _assigned to var1 it gets updated but the template doesn't render the updated values_ - that's weird, can you create a plunker?

Comment: That is actually weird. I'll try to put this into a plunkr over the coming weekend. But for the time being, Im thinking to use the values directly from the service. What are your thoughts on that? @Maximus

Comment: @Aiguo, I don't know) At the first glance seems strange solution